# Conflicting Intel graphics driver on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: drivers, 22.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a brand new PC with an Intel UHD graphics card. I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 and installed it. I changed the desktop from Wayland to Xorg. I then installed `vainfo` utility to check `libva` information. `Vainfo` returns iHD driver information successfully.

I installed Chrome and when I try to watch 4k video, the console shows the following error:

```
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
```

How do I solve this problem so I can get hardware acceleration in Chrome?